# SQL Server Function To Check String Based on Format and Convert to Date

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am working on a system where a table column with datatype of varchar is storing dates as string in different formats. For example:

```
12 Mar 2011
01/03/2011
2011/03/05
01/05/11
01/Mar/2010
```

The crux of the matter is that since the table is being populated by more than 40 different applications (half of them does not even have a source code to begin modifying with), I am left with no choice but to work on what data is available to me.

Has anyone devised a function that would check how the string is stored in the column, and as necessary, apply the proper conversion to the appropriate date time data type?

```
Example below:
DateTime Value stored as String     |     SQL Convert Script
Dec 01 2010                               CONVERT(datetime, 'Dec 01 2010', 100)
10/23/2016                                CONVERT(datetime, '10/23/2016', 101
2016.10.23                                CONVERT(datetime, 2016.10.23, 102)
```

..and so on.

Of course this is not a foolproof way since there are times that dates may be stored where the months and the days are interchanged.

Thanks.

Comment: From other columns in the row, do you have a way to know whether 6/5/2010 is 6th of May or 5th of June?

Comment: Even based on your sample data, how do you know that `01/05/11` is Jan 5th instead of May 1st or that `01/03/2011` is Jan 3rd instead of Mar 1st?

Comment: If there are 40 apps writing data in all sorts of formats, how is this data being consumed? What are the apps doing with the data? Would any conversion routine need to be a one-time thing or is this on-going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone devised a function that would check how the string is stored in the column, and as necessary, apply the proper conversion to the appropriate date time data type?

Yes, SQL Server can do that.

> Of course this is not a foolproof way since there are times that dates may be stored where the months and the days are interchanged.

That is correct. You have to help a bit by specifying the most likely [dateformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx).

```
set dateformat mdy
--set dateformat dmy

declare @T table (dt varchar(50))
insert into @T values
('12 Mar 2011'),
('01/03/2011'),
('2011/03/05'),
('01/05/11'),
('01/Mar/2010')

select cast(dt as datetime)
from @T
```

Result with `mdy`

```
Date
-----------------------
2011-03-12 00:00:00.000
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000
2011-03-05 00:00:00.000
2011-01-05 00:00:00.000
2010-03-01 00:00:00.000
```

Result with `dmy`

```
Date
-----------------------
2011-03-12 00:00:00.000
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
2011-05-03 00:00:00.000
2011-05-01 00:00:00.000
2010-03-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood the documentation for CONVERT.  Using the format like that applies to converting a datetime *to* a string, not vice versa.  As Michael Eriksson's answer indicates, taking a string and converting it to a datetime usually does the right thing.